# How to use FragmentLayout without extending Fragment class

Tags: android, fragment, extend

I am creating fragment using class from another package

```
//ONCREATE
PickKanjiActivity pickKanji=new PickKanjiActivity();

//SOME_METHOD
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.frameKanji, pickKanji);
fTrans.commit();
```

But this code is giving following error:

> The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, PickKanjiActivity)

Then I tought that I should extend Fragment in PickKanjiActivity like this:

```
public class PickKanjiActivity extends Fragment
```

But PickKanjiActivity already extending another class

```
public class PickKanjiActivity extends KanjiActivity
```

Question is how to create fragment without extending Fragment?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve, but use `<fragment>` tag and put the fragment in your xml.

Answer (score 4):

You don't.  Their PickKanjiActivity is an activity, not a fragment.  You'd need to rewrite their code as a fragment.  You can't just use it as one when it isn't one.